# Undefined error when passing row.entity and col.field to function

Tags: javascript, angular, undefined, angular-ui-grid, ui-grid

I need row.entity and col.field to determine if a button needs to be disabled or not, so here's the code for the cellTemplate of my UI-grid

```
      cellTemplate:
     '<div *ngIf="{{COL_FIELD}}"> '+
        '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" > {{COL_FIELD}}' +
           '<button  uib-tooltip="Modifica" tooltip-placement="auto" ng-disabled="grid.appScope.modificaDisabled(row.entity, col.field)"'+
               'rel= "{{row.entity}}" rol="{{col.field}}" '+
               'class="btn btn-xs btn-primary stretto" style="float:right;" edit>'+
               '<i class="fa fa-pencil fa-fw"></i>'+
           '</button>'+
        '</div>'+
     '</div>'
```

and here's the function called

```
var modificaDisabled = function(riga,col){
        console.log(riga)
        console.log(col)
        //disabling logic
        }
```

The problem ( *sgrid.appScope.modificaDisabled(row.entity, **col.field**)* ) is that the second parameter passed (in this case **col.field**) results undefined but if i switch their position (col.field, row.entity ) **col.field** is actually defined but then **row.entity** results undefined.

Can anyone help me? I've seen another post talking about the spacing after the comma, but nothing seems to work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a "solution" :

```
ng-disabled="grid.appScope.modificaDisabled([row.entity, col.field])"
```

by passing the values as an array I get them defined (idk why) and i can finally proceed